# Google Maps v2 for Android map tiles overlapping

Tags: android, google-maps, mapbox

I use custom UrlTileProvider to load tiles from MapBox.

```
public class MapboxTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

public MapboxTileProvider(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
}

@Override
public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int z) {
    try {
        return new URL(String.format(MAP_BASE_URL, z, x, y));
    }  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed constructing map tile URL", e);
    }
} }
```

It loads correctly, but what I see is that default Google tiles are overlapping MapBox's ones.[image]
[image: those yellow roads from google tiles]
(those yellow roads are definitely from google maps)

How can I disable default tiles and prevent them from loading?

I use nested SupportMapFragment initialized like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, mapFragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (map == null) {
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        map.clear();
        map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(new MapboxTileProvider(MapboxTileProvider.MAP_TILE_DIMENSION, MapboxTileProvider.MAP_TILE_DIMENSION)));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
```

Refs:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMapType(int)
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#MAP_TYPE_NONE

Comment: Thank you, that was somewhat obvious.